# Trying to learn RoR, but keep getting Page doesn't exist errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn RoR and I keep getting pesky page doesn't exist pages. I deleted the index.html file out of my public folder and created a root route in my routes file but I still am getting that error. I am running ubuntu 10.04 with mod_passenger and ruby enterprise edition.

Comment: Can you paste your routes file, and the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: Are your route points to correct controller and action names? Do the controller and action exist? Do you have the corresponding view files?

Comment: Could you show the exact error you're getting and the steps you go through to make it happen? It could mean either that it can't find a model's object or it's the 404.html page.

Comment: Are you using passenger in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. just leave the mod_passenger until you find the error. Do like this:

   - open a shell
   - go to your Rails app directory
   - `ruby script/server` (Rails < 3).

     It should start the server in your console. and browse the page you want. If you are getting an error it should display in the console.
2. check your database connection is OK in `config/database.yml` file

Answer (score 0):

`rake routes` is the standard shell command to see all your routes. Check if url you're trying to access is in the list. If it's not, show us statement in `routes.rb` you use to generate this route and url you're trying to access.

Comment: Yeah the url is on there, but now I'm getting a "something went wrong error" with nothing logged at all.

Comment: @Kyle Check server logs. If you started server through console command, error will also be displayed in console.

Comment: If not, you can check the contents of ~RAILS_ROOT/log/development.log

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the content of your routes.rb file?
Also, make sure you have a controller created for that page and it should contain the index action.

def index
end